# How would I extend WebAPI to support returning controller action results via an HTTP callback?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to extend WebAPI to support returning a response through an HTTP callback.

Workflow:

1. WebAPI receives a HTTP request with a callback URL.
2. WebAPI handles the URL normally and if the operation completes in less time than a configured timeout the result is sent synchronously.
3. If the timeout is exceeded the server needs to send an HTTP response indicating it went async, processing continues.
4. When processing (eventually) completes the response of the controller is posted to the pre-negotiated callback url.

Controllers need to remain synchronous and unaware of the async/callback functionality.

It appears MessageHandlers are a likely candidate but returning multiple HTTP responses (one for the early 'long task' response and one for the callback) does not appear to be supported.

Can someone provide guidance on what areas of WebAPI are extensible and relevant to this scenario?

Comment: this logic might not be the best solution for this job. I think you can divide potentially long/expensive jobs as queue based proccess. And finaly manage this queues with a scheduled background task. So, whit this approach you can simplify api action by just "adding new task to queue" :)

Answer (score 0):

I think an HttpMessageHandler will do the trick but not the way I think you're asking for.

One URL will be the main one and will return either the result or the redirection and the other will handle the redirections.

This is a very common scenario. In some cases you'll ask for a list of something and receive the a managed amount of results and a continuation URL if there are more. You requirement might be looked up as being just that where you either only have a continuation or the whole results.

Another way of looking at it as CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation). You issue a command to on URL and retrieve the response from another. As an optimization, the result of invoking the command might be the response instead of the query URL.

Does this help you?